# Meteor-slingshot s3 to non-cors compatible server

Tags: amazon-s3, meteor, meteor-slingshot

Im trying to use meteor-slingshot to connect to a s3 protocol nodechef object server with that does not support cors configurations, and does not use regions, just bucket + endpoint + filename and im receiving:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at [server] from origin [local] has been
>   blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass
>   access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource.

Im fairly certain this is from the lack of cors configuration. Is there anyway to disable cors requirements of slingshot or any other way to get past this?